# STM32H7 and timer-triggered DFSDM conversion - how to?

Tags: stm32, stm32h7

For the last two evenings I have been trying to set up timer-triggered DFSDM conversion on STM32H7A3 MPU with no luck. Googling I hound no single complete example, perhaps because DFSDM is more advanced topic.
Objective: fill the filter buffer with N samples every 1s.
I attach screenshots of the CubeMX setup. The conversion works as expected in the continuous mode, so the channel and clock setup is correct.
In code, before starting the 1s timer (`HAL_TIM_Base_Start()`) I call `HAL_DFSDM_FilterInjectedMsbStart_DMA()`.
Neither `DFSDM1_FLT2_IRQHandler()` nor `DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler()` is being fired.
What am I missing?

[image: filter setup]

[image: DMA setup]

[image: timer 7 setup]

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with this setup. The problem was that filter buffer was way too large and I was not patient enough.
However, this approach does not fulfill my needs. On every timer tick a new value is added to the buffer and `HAL_DFSDM_FilterInjConvCpltCallback()` is called only when filter buffers gets full. To get series of quick measurements (e.g. 1kHz rate) I could increase timer speed but that would put too much unnecessary load on CPU while I do not care about the exact rate as long as it is known. I would be better off using regular conversion started at (e.g.) 1s interval.